# Estou com esse erro e nao sei como resolver, meu angular é v.14

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, angularjs-directives, angular-material

img de exemplo:

[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7Vfv.png)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Está escrito que precisa ter entre 7 e 8 argumentos e pelo que contei você está passando 9 argumentos, teria que tirar o argumento que está a mais conforme a sua programação ou documentação do ngx-toastr

Comment: static ɵcmp: i0.ɵɵComponentDeclaration<ToastNoAnimation, "[toast-component]", never, {}, {}, never, never, false, never>; -->I removed the last never and it was like this -> 
static ɵcmp: i0.ɵɵComponentDeclaration<ToastNoAnimation, "[toast-component]", never, {}, {}, never, never, false>;. It works !!!. Tanks